# Remove tax from the invoice pdf

Tags: magento

I've been trying to remove this single line(Tax: ) from the invoice pdf. It didn't know it's going to be so hard and going cost me 5 hours and I am still stuck.

Its the print button in sales invoice.. in Admin
[image]

Please help!

My last try was

placing  in `if($totalInfo['source_field'] == 'tax_amount') {continue;}` foreach below()

In _getTotalsList($Source) in Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract (Which I am gonna override later)

```
    protected function _getTotalsList($source)
{
    $totals = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/pdf/totals')->asArray();
    usort($totals, array($this, '_sortTotalsList'));
    $totalModels = array();
    foreach ($totals as $index => $totalInfo) {
```

`if($totalInfo['source_field'] == 'tax_amount') {continue;}`

```
        if (!empty($totalInfo['model'])) {
            $totalModel = Mage::getModel($totalInfo['model']);
            if ($totalModel instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default) {
                $totalInfo['model'] = $totalModel;
            } else {
                Mage::throwException(
                    Mage::helper('sales')->__('PDF total model should extend Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default')
                );
            }
        } else {
            $totalModel = Mage::getModel($this->_defaultTotalModel);
        }
        $totalModel->setData($totalInfo);
        $totalModels[] = $totalModel;
    }

    return $totalModels;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Tax column from the magento PDF invoice-

The two files you need to edit are:

- To remove headers:
  `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`
- To rmove the tax from each individual line item
  `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php`

Hope this will help you!!

other wise,

Refer this [links](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/231641/#t423108)

Comment: I've tried that but the thing is. It removes the horizontal line in the pdf which have the same information like products name sku subtotal tax etc.  But It doesn't remove the tax from the Grand Total like in the picture in my question(vertical rows). Those are seems to get handled from somewhere else. I've changed the image please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove this line because still grand total would be 1.10, just hidden. If you don't want tax in your products just disable it in magento configuration.

Go to:

```
Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules
```

And set taxes for all client groups as 0.

Answer (score 0):

The two magento core classes responsible for displaying the tax summary in pdf are

```
Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Pdf_Tax 
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default
```

You can oerride these class files to display the tax info as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem myself a few times, and found a couple of hacky ways around it, but today I think I finally found the "correct" solution.

If you look in layout/sales.xml you'll find a number of nodes that include a block with a name of `order_totals`, and inside that, a block with a name of `tax`. This is what's responsible for that row appearing in your PDF.

I would suggest the "proper" way to remove it, then, is to add this to your layout/local.xml file:

```
<sales_order_printinvoice>
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <remove name="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_printinvoice>
```

(If you don't have a layout/local.xml file, just create one.)

This removes it from the *invoice* printout, which is what is mentioned in the question. To remove it from other places make sure you have the right node name - so for example, to remove it from the *order* printout that the customer can access from their order history, use this:

```
<sales_order_print>
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <remove name="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_print>
```

...and so on for emails, etc. Just have a look in layout/sales.xml for every occurrence of `_totals` to see all the affected nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you may try in Admin 
 `System > Configuration > Sales > Tax`
from that select 
 
`Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings` tab and set 
 `Display Full Tax Summary` as `No`. There are different setting given too. That will help.
[image]